# HTML Canvas resize issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, html5-canvas

I am trying to resize my canvas to fit inside it's parent div inside of a Bootstrap grid, however the canvas keeps filling to 2000px x 2000px. It seems from console.log that I am successfully resizing, as they return the same dimensions. The 'Hello World' div is just there for testing.

HTML

```
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-10">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row justify-content-center">
                            <div class="col-8 text-center">
                                <div class="bg-gradient-danger w-100">Hello World</div>
                                <br>
                                <div id="canvasBox"
                                     style="padding: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;border: 4px solid navy;">
                                    <canvas id="canvas" width="1" height="1"></canvas>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Javascript

```
        let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        let parent = document.getElementById('canvasBox');
        let imgUrl = document.getElementById('canvasIMG');
        let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        let wdt = parent.clientWidth - parseInt(parent.style.paddingLeft) - parseInt(parent.style.paddingRight);
        let ht = parent.clientHeight - parseInt(parent.style.paddingTop) - parseInt(parent.style.paddingBottom);

        console.log(wdt, ht)
        canvas.setAttribute('width', wdt + "px");
        canvas.setAttribute('height', ht + "px");
        console.log(canvas.width, canvas.height)
        ctx.drawImage(imgUrl, 0, 0);
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Below is a screenshot of the result, where the canvas keeps overflowing.

[image: Result]

Comment: I think you don't need the + "px". Just the plain Int value

Comment: The issue can be that you draw the canvas just once on initial load. You can make a function of the width and height settings and the canvas drawing and call it on some kind of a resize event that it refreshes the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your initial width and height values are also wrong. You can refresh on page load and on resize to fit the canvas:

```js
                  let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        let parent = document.getElementById('canvasBox');
        let imgUrl = document.getElementById('canvasIMG');
        let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        function refresh() {
          let wdt = parent.clientWidth - parseInt(parent.style.paddingLeft) - parseInt(parent.style.paddingRight);
        let ht = parent.clientHeight - parseInt(parent.style.paddingTop) - parseInt(parent.style.paddingBottom);

        canvas.setAttribute('width', wdt + "px");
        canvas.setAttribute('height', ht + "px");

          ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        };

window.addEventListener('load', refresh);
window.addEventListener('resize', refresh);
```

```html
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-10">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row justify-content-center">
                            <div class="col-8 text-center">
                                <div class="bg-gradient-danger w-100">Hello World</div>
                                <br>
                                <div id="canvasBox"
                                     style="padding: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;border: 4px solid navy;">
                                    <canvas id="canvas" width="1" height="1"></canvas>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the canvas to fir the inside of the blue box is to use `style="width: 100%"` on the canvas:

```
<canvas id="canvas" style="width: 100%;" height="200px"></canvas>
```

This does not set a height based on the user's window size, but using the `clientHeight` may result in unfavorable aspect ratios if the user does not have the same size window you are testing in.

This solution gives the result:

[image: Solution preview]